# Ubuntu starting from live CD, flashing screen?

Tags: 12.04, boot, 13.04, live-usb, live-cd

I got SICK AND TIRED of Windows 8, so I decided I was gonna install Ubuntu. I burned 12.04 LTS to a disc, but it just stayed there with a black screen. Sometimes I'd get lucky and have a flashing screen from blac to purple, other times I'd get REALLY lucky and have a solid screen, and if I moved the mouse up, I could see the cursor there. I tried putting `nomodeset` in the boot commands, but it says something along the lines of "Command not recognized" and comes up with the flashing screen. The same stuff happens when I use a live USB with 13.04.
I am using a Dell XPS 8700. I tried turning off Secure Boot, but the same thing happens.
If anyone can help me, I gove you my thanks in advance.

-Zakee

Answer (score 0):

Zakee,

EDIT: PLEASE REFER TO THE DUPLICATE LINK LUCIO HAS PROVIDED AS IT COVERS IT MORE DETAIL!

Try and see if you can get to a BIOS boot screen, depending on the UEFI BIOS, you could potentially use the Ubuntu UEFI loader which could give you better results. [This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) has more information for you, as in making sure you have the 64-bit download, changing BIOS to support Legacy etc.

Good Luck!