# New Windows 8 branded computer, fresh Ubuntu installation

Tags: installation, boot, 13.04

I bought a new computer with the Windows 8 so I tried installing Ubuntu 13.04.

However when installation is finished and you get the final "remove cd and hit enter" part of the installation, that's is where my game ends.  You can remove the CD (you have to do it manually, it doesn't pop out) but after that game-over.  Ended up having to hard-reset.

When the computer restarts an all black screen echoes back:

> Reboot and Select proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media...

Everyone points to the Boot Repair disk to solve the problems, but when I do that it gives me the same error message about "Reboot and Select proper..."

I'm wondering where, or what I have done wrong.

Comment: Did you reviewed [this useful post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to set your BIOS to Legacy Boot Mode, I found more information on this [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) but haven't had to worry about setting it personally. So the link provided by Ubuntu themselves is the best I can give you.

Comment: trying that now.

Comment: This made bootup behave a little bit different. I'm going to try installing it fresh again just to be sure I have everything good to go.  I will report back as soon as installation succeeds or fails.  Thank you so much for your information!

Comment: @Cole Your answer remember to another one very similar.. http://askubuntu.com/a/327984/62483 You should take a look at a couple of meta post like [this one](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3608/62483)

Comment: @Cole Your solution worked. This is William the OP who posted this. Please message me privately, I must inquire about something in private.  I hope you have a lovely day. Go to bed knowing you totally changed the course of someone's day for the better.

Comment: @Lucio I believe you mean to say that I have said this answer before and that this particular user was not looking through posts before asking questions. You are correct but this user may have a different problem than the previous user. The difference is that they did not know that it can be fixed the same way. Also, marking as duplicates cannot be done by someone of my reputation level so for that I must say Thanks for linking my other answer with the same method that will cover multiple bases.

Comment: @user49777 Unfortunately there is no private messaging feature on StackExchange's network.

Comment: @user49777 Please, mark the answer as accepted so this post remains as answered.

Comment: @Cole: I'm thirdwilliam on Twitter. HMU!

Comment: @user49777 check your most recent follower